# How to modify Qt/PyQt install on OSX

Tags: python, pyqt

After hours of QT/PyQt compiling and tedious installation there is new `./PyQt4/` sub-folder under `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`.

Since I don't want to run the same compilation/installation process on every mac machine I thought I just would copy/paste that '`PyQt4` folder and import it using:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt4')
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

But I am getting a following `ImportError`:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/_qt.so, 2): Library not loaded: QtDesigner.framework/Versions/4/QtDesigner
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/_qt.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Apparently it looks for some additional files. Where what are they?

Comment: Before you compile, make sure you parallelize the built. It should be much faster, then. `export MAKEFLAGS=-j$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)`

Comment: Thanks Kuba! Would you please clarify where exactly this flag needs to be defined. And what is the `parallelization` in this context?

Comment: Just type it in the shell prior to running the build. It needs to be in the same shell, of course. Parallelization means that make will run multiple processes in parallel, up to the number of available CPUs. You paid for all those cores, now get to use them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.so` files are [shared objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries) there were created when you compiled PyQT on the system.  Qt references these files at runtime.

That said, linking these files might be more trouble than just documenting and scripting your install process.

Comment: So, there is no way to re-link the shared objects so PyQt could find them?

Comment: You could copy all the files touched by compilation, but unless every mac you buy is the same, it's not really worth the trouble.